# "At least one" Argument Error despite proper method call

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to solve a Ruby challenge where I define a method that determines whether a number is of the type 'Kaprekar'. I keep getting the following argument:

```
C:\Users\Lemuel\Desktop\RubyProjects\RubyMonk>ruby kaprekars_n.rb
   kaprekars_n.rb:8:in `count': wrong number of arguments (at least 1) (ArgumentError)
    from kaprekars_n.rb:8:in `kaprekars'
    from kaprekars_n.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

After the following code:

```
 def kaprekars(n)
  numStr = n.to_s 
  numDigits = numStr.count numStr
  squareNum = n*n
  x = []
  squareNum.to_s.each_char {|c| x << c }
  l = x[0..(numDigits-1)].inject(:+)
  r = x[l.count..(x.count)].inject(:+)
  sum = l+r 
  sum == n ? true : false
 end

puts kaprekars(2)
```

Experiments in the terminal show that I'm using the count method correctly so I don't understand the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `count` in more than one place, your problem is in line `8`:

```
r = x[l.count..(x.count)].inject(:+)
```

It should be:

```
r = x[l.size..(x.size)].inject(:+)
```

Some explanation - both [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-count) and [`String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-count) have a `count` method, but they are different, and expect different number of parameters:

- Array's `count` returns the number of elements in the array, or the number of elements equal to the parameter given (if one is given)
- String's `count` counts the number of characters *matching the intersection of character sets given as parameters*. It expects *at least* one string parameter.

Both [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-size) and [`String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-size) also have a `size` method, which returns the size of the `Array` or `String`.

When you first call `numStr.count numStr` you are effectively counting all the characters in the string, so you could have used `numStr.size` as well, but it is a legitimate call as it is.

In line 8, you try to call `count` on `x` (which is an array) and on `l` (which is a string) without any parameter, which causes the failure.

Comment: Thank You. I wasn't familiar with the size method. Can you explain why I can only use the count method in one place?